# Generated Gif is too large - ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, io, uiimageview, uiimage, cgimage

I am generating gif using the following method.

```
-(void)makeAnimatedGif:(NSArray *)imgArray {
    __block NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //Do background work
        NSUInteger kFrameCount = imgArray.count;

        NSDictionary *fileProperties = @{
                                         (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                                                 (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount: @0, // 0 means loop forever
                                                 }
                                         };

        NSDictionary *frameProperties = @{
                                          (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                                                  (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime: @0.02f, // a float (not double!) in seconds, rounded to centiseconds in the GIF data
                                                  }
                                          };

        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];

        NSURL *fileURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, kUTTypeGIF, kFrameCount, NULL);
        CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)fileProperties);

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < kFrameCount; i++) {
            @autoreleasepool {
                UIImage *image =[imgArray objectAtIndex:i];  //Here is the change
                if (image.CGImage) {
                    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image.CGImage, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)) {
            NSLog(@"failed to finalize image destination");
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Update UI
            CFRelease(destination);
            [self manageGifWithUrl:fileURL];
        });
    });

}
```

The problem with my gif is that the size is very large. Size of generated gif ranges from 40MB - 90MB. I am not able to find any solution for this.

My imgArray contains 180 images. Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a video, encode a video.  Animated GIFs are awful for encapsulating video like animations.  They've only become so common because every browser can render them.  Unless your goal is cross-platform lowest common denominator playback, don't use animate gifs.

40-80MB doesn't sound that surprising.   To reduce the size, reduce the resolution of the input images-- either by simply making them smaller or by reducing the color palette so they compress better.

Comment: can you provide any link or resource for doing the same. It would be really helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, actually encoding video isn't something I have much experience with (I wrote a GIF89a decoder ages ago, which is why I knew what I did :). I'd suggest a new SO question once you do a bit of investigation.